# copying data from Parent Repeating Section to Child Repeating section in infopath

Tags: formula, xpath, infopath-2007, repeat

I am having an issue with the repeating section. The scenario is i am having a text box inside a repeating section and a checkbox outside a repeating scetion. I want the value of the textbox to be copied when the repeating section is repeated. This has to be done when i click teh checkbox which is outside the repeating section. I used Xpath formula for this. it works fine if i just repeat the section but not when i click the checkbox which is outside the repeating section.

The formula is as follows

```
../preceding-sibling::my:RepeatingSection[
   count(../preceding-sibling::my:RepeatingSection)
    = count(current()/../preceding-sibling::my:RepeatingSection)
    - last()
]/my:TextBox
```

This formula works fine for a single repeating section. But i also have another problem if there are nested sections. for example if i have a repeating section and another repeating section inside it and the textbox inside the nested section. The problem is writing the correct path to navigate within the sections.

Can anyone please help me with this issue

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: @user570423: I don't really understand this... It looks like you are using XSLT `current()` function. I think you should post the stylesheet, the input sample and the desired output

Comment: This is not in XSLT. I can explain my scenario more briefly. If the check box is selected and when the repeating section is repeated the value in the parent section of the textbox should be copied to the child section. I can give you a daily life example of my scenario, my task is similar to the shopping cart where we fill in the data for the shipping address fields and if we want the same address to the billing address then we click the check box for the address fields to get copied.

Comment: Please, edit your question to provide the source XML document (as minimal as possible) and explain which nodes do you want to select.